# Obejective-C. Nature of undefined behavior when method is overridden in category

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

I read this:

> Avoid Category Method Name Clashes
>
> Because the methods declared in a category are added to an existing class, you need to be very careful about method names.
>
> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, or a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime. This is less likely to be an issue if you’re using categories with your own classes, but can cause problems when using categories to add methods to standard Cocoa or Cocoa Touch classes.

But I'm interested why it happens. I suspect that it is because how method dispatching works in Objective-C but I wasn't able to find any article that would explain it with categories.

How categories modify method list?
Why it causes undefined behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The source to the runtime is available.  You can read the definitive truth. :)

In abstract terms, the way the runtime optimizes the method lists for dispatches has changed over time.   Overriding methods via categories has always been sketchy because you are effectively "losing" an implementation when you do that.  If the method being lost is on the core class, it may have implementation details that grub around in the innards of the class in a way that a method loaded later should not do.

So, there is very little effort placed on making the behavior consistent.   Especially if consistency were to cost speed.

Comment: Two answers in a week? Are you back on SO? You've been missed.

Comment: @RobNapier Had some exceptionally long install times this week... ;)

Comment: Also, at some point there were some issues with categories being dynamically loaded into the binary, but not properly flushing the method caches, a long while back in the runtime. Nasty stuff, and while it's been fixed for several years, just another example why you shouldn't do that.